# Android - Converting string to list to push to firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to convert the string below to a list?
This string is retrieved after scanning a QR code.

```
CashRequest{
    orderid='0',
    user_id='nvHt2U5RnqUwXB4ZK37Zn1DXPV82',
    userName='username',
    userEmail='whateveremailthisis@email.blabla',
    fullName='full name',
    phoneNumber=0,
    totalCash='$304.00',
    totalRV='$34.00', 

    foods=[
        Order{
            userID='nvHt2U5RnqUwXB4ZK37Zn1DXPV82',
            ProductID='-LMDiT7klgoXU8bQEM-4',
            ProductName='Coke',
            Quantity='4',
            Price='1',
            RedemptionPrice='10',
            RedemptionValue='1'},
        Order{
            userID='nvHt2U5RnqUwXB4ZK37Zn1DXPV82',
            ProductID='1000',
            ProductName='Kunau Ring Ring Pradu',
            Quantity='3',
            Price='100',
            RedemptionPrice='10',
            RedemptionValue='10'
        }
    ]
}
```

The desired output is to store it in firebase realtime database as below :

[image]

Comment: What data format is that?  It's not json, xml, or anything else I recognise.  Do you have control over the data in the QR code?  If you do, I recommend putting it in json instead of that format.  Then you can use built-in android methods to parse it.  

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: @rexar5, yes i do have control over the QR code.   <br/>
    
    CashRequest cashRequest = new CashRequest(
                        "0",
                        userID,
                        userName,
                        userEmail,
                        fullName,
                        phoneNumber,
                        totalCash.getText().toString(),
                        totalRV.getText().toString(),
                        cart
                );
                showQRDialog();
                QRgen(String.valueOf(cashRequest));

Comment: Oh, awesome!  So what you'll want to do is just change your CashRequest object's toString function (and also whatever object is represented by the cart variable).  I would probably recommend a toJson method that outputs a json object with all the fields set and the toString just calls toString on that json object.  You'll also give it a second constructor that will take a json string and set all the data from that.  You can use this tutorial to make this work.  It isn't too complex, but let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html

I recommend json for serialization/deserialization of objects because Android supports it out of the box and it's very commonly used, so it's a good tool to know how to use.  Firebase also probably handles it out of the box, though I am not too familiar with firebase DBs like you posted.

Comment: If you update your question with your code for the cart class and any subclasses it used (order?) and the CashRequest class, I can add json versions to the answer.

Comment: @rexar5 thank you. I tried your suggestion by modifying the toString into a proper json for and it worked as well!

Comment: Show us what you try, your attempts.

Comment: @JonathanGagne 
https://imgur.com/Th8pJNy - The QR gen side. 

 https://imgur.com/a/PHnpwFC - The QR scanner side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a few options. Since it is newline between values, you could use simple newline reads and compare if it starts with "reserved word that you are looking for" then substring from there, but that can get messy and a lot of bloat code.

The simplest way would be to do the known replace first.
Make a method that replaces all bad json keys with quote surrounded json keys like:

```
 val myJsonCorrected = yourStringAbove.replace("Order", "\"Order"\")
```

repeat for all known entities until you have made it into valid json. Single ticks are fine for the values, but the keys need quotes as well.

Then simply create an object that matches the json format.

```
class CashRequestModel{
      @SerializableName("orderid")
      var orderID: Int? = null
      etc.....
      @SerializableName("foods")
      var myFoods: ArrayList<OrderModel>? = null
}

class OrderMode {
     @SerializableName("userID")
     var userID: String? = null
     @SerializableName("ProductID")
     var userID: String? = null
     etc..
}
```

Then simply convert it to JSON

```
val cashRequest = getGson().fromJson(cleanedUpJson, classTypeForCashRequest);
```

and your done. Now just use the list. Of course it would be better if you could get valid JSON without having to clean it up first, but it looks like the keys are known and you can easily code string replaces to fix the bad json before casting it to object that matches the structure.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to help. :)